# Batch-based video game problems

Tags: batch-file, frames

I'm making another batch based video game and its like a maze game and I have the controls set up, but I was wondering if there's any way to have an "on collision" event in the script so that instead of mapping out every possible position of where the character in the game could be, I could just make it so that if nothing is in front of the character then move forward but if something is in front of it, then replay this frame (stay in same position) I will have the link to my current gaming script at the bottom of this post. Say if I had a simplified map that looked something like this:

```
@echo off
title level 1
cls
:MAIN
echo °°°°°°°ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º       º       º X º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º Û º       º       º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
goto MAIN
```

My current controls would be:

```
choice /c awsd /n 
IF %errorlevel%==2 goto a2
IF %errorlevel%==1 goto a1
IF %errorlevel%==4 goto a1
IF %errorlevel%==3 goto a1
goto a1
```

But the problem with this method is that a new copy of this code (called a frame) will have to be re-typed below it for every character space that the user makes the character move in game. (Again, examples of this are given in my current game file at the bottom) what I wanted was something like:

```
@echo off
title level 1
cls
:MAIN
echo °°°°°°°ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   Û   º       º X º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º       º       º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼°°°°°°°°°°°°°°

:a1
choice /c awsd /n 
IF %errorlevel%==2 goto a2check
IF %errorlevel%==1 goto a3
IF %errorlevel%==4 goto a3
IF %errorlevel%==3 goto a3
goto a1


:a2check
set /p collision=<collision_check.bat
IF %collision%==yes goto collision_confirm
IF %collision%==no goto a2
goto MAIN

:collision_confirm
cls
goto MAIN


:a3
cls
:: somehow edit the map so that the character "Û" moves to the position 
:: specified by the user in the choice command section.

:: so the new position would be: 

echo °°°°°°°ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º     Û º       º X º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º   º   º   º   º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°º   º       º       º°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
echo °°°°°°°ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼°°°°°°°°°°°°°°


goto a3
```

The collision_check.bat file is what I need help with, I need a script that would define all the collision points in the givin map and then tell the level file if the character in the game is about to hit one. I know this is a lot to take on in one project but I wanted a challenge!

Comment: Probably you are not the first to try to solve this issues ... but all others already picked up another language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with batch, too.

But you should try to solve it with another solution.

The level should be hold in variables/arrays.
The position is only a coordinate x,y in this array.
Then you only need a display function for the array.
And you can "detect" collisions by asking your array.

This should help

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set line[0]=#####
set line[1]=# # #
set line[2]=# # #
set line[3]=# # #
set line[4]=#   #
set line[5]=#####
set pos.x=3
set pos.y=1

:game
call :display
call :Move
goto :game

:display
cls
set /a xAdd1=pos.x+1
for /L %%n in (0,1,5) do (
    set line=!line[%%n]!
    if %%n==%pos.y% (
        set line=!line:~0,%pos.x%!X!line:~%xAdd1%!
    )
    echo !line!
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: that looks like it should work but im not sure how to insert that script into my script successfully, could you possibly follow the link in my original post (level one) and apply your concept to mine? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

this makes everything easier:

BatBox is an external command that allows using console graphicaly, but not only. It enables also user interractions such as mouse.

For example, BatBox allows console cursor position to be changed, change loccally console's colors, or even get user mouse inputs.

http://dos9.org/doc/en/html/batbox.html